# Certification tracking software

Tags: project-management

I work for a small (less than 50 employees) family business involved in general contracting (construction).

This business often bids/works government contracts and I am responsible for numerous regulatory duties. I would like to keep track of:

- all clearances/certifications we have on file/have received from subcontractors
- the expiration dates of these certifications
- what governing body they have been submitted to
- when they have been submitted

I'd use Excel but it has become ungainly/hell to me. I cannot spend time considering whether they have Excel in Hell or just in my personal hell. There has to be a better way, a path woven in gold and productivity.

Anyways, piggybacking any recommendation for GC-targeted software would also be good to me too (e.g. viewpoint/newforma). I'm hella lazy and love to automate that workflow.

Comment: I know this question goes back a couple of years, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you resolved this, but I have done something related/similar for a construction-related business using [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) content management framework running on a company's intranet or on internet.

1. By default it gives you a multi-user environment. You can even expand it with its [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module to enable login using Active Directory/LDAP accounts.
2. It uses MySql database. You can email users, add images, files, etc
3. You can create "content types" for your information-type, and add fields for: clearances/certifications, expiration dates, governing bodies, etc.
4. Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create simple queries/display of the
   information.
5. The [Search modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) with search_api_db, search_api_solr etc can enable you create simple or sophisticated searches

There is some learning curve to put it all together. But it is flexible for changes, especially since organisation requirements can change with time.